# slide content in on button click

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin

I have sign up and sign in layout files (both with form elements on them), a home page (Main.axml) with a two buttons which each setContentView() to their particular layout. When you click the sign up button the signup layout should slide in from the right all the way, covering the home page and the same for the sign in page. Almost setting new content view but the view slide in all the way like Spotify login/signup on their app.

Which component am I best using, viewPage, DialogFragment, hidden content with animation? What do you guys think is best?

Best example I want to follow is Spotify's app home page when you have yet to sign up/in.

You are greeted by a screen with two buttons, login/signup. Say for example you click the signup then the signup page slides in from the right fully covering the main screen.

Image below demonstrates:

[image]

How can I duplicate this with Android built in Xamarin C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at "Navigation Drawer". Hope it helps you.

[Navigation Drawer - Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

[Navigation Drawer - Xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/NavigationDrawer/)

Comment: Thanks, looks promising :)

Comment: Looking for a Material Design Web format for this. the kind where it would fit in for all devices